# How to join two table from two different edmx using linq query

Tags: linq, entity-framework, edmx

How to join two table from two different edmx using linq query..
Is there a way to query from 2 different edmx at a time.

Thanks.

Comment: show us your table contents !

Comment: I have 100 tables in edmx1 and 100 at edmx2.. just wanna linq query to join a table1 from edmx1 and table 2 from edmx2

Comment: I've updated the answer - I'm rather hoping you are dealing with (or can filter) only a small set of data from both tables prior to the join.

Answer (score 5):

**Update**

As per your comment, EF wasn't able to parse a combined Expression tree across 2 different contexts.

If the total number of records in the tables is relatively small, or if you can reduce the number of records in the join to a small number of rows (say < 100 each), then you can materialize the data (e.g. `.ToList() / .ToArray() / .AsEnumerable()`) from both tables and use the `Linq join` as per below.

e.g. where `yesterday` is a `DateTime` selecting just a small set of data from both databases required for the join:

```
var reducedDataFromTable1 = context1.Table1
                                    .Where(data => data.DateChanged > yesterday)
                                    .ToList();
var reducedDataFromTable2 = context2.Table2
                                    .Where(data => data.DateChanged > yesterday)
                                    .ToList();
var joinedData = reducedDataFromTable1
                         .Join(reducedDataFromTable2,
                               t1 => t1.Id,    // Join Key on table 1
                               t2 => t2.T1Id,  // Join Key on table 2
                               (table1, table2) => ... // Projection
                               );
```

However, if the data required from both databases for the join is larger than could reasonably expected to be done in memory, then you'll need to investigate alternatives, such as:

- Can you do the cross database join in the database? If so, look at using a Sql projection such as a view to do the join, which you can then use in your edmx.
- Otherwise, you are going to need to do the join by manually iterating the 2 enumerables, something like [chunking](http://www.lyquidity.com/devblog/?p=94) - this isn't exactly trivial. Sorting the data in both tables by the same order will help.

**Original Answer**

I believe you are looking for the Linq [JOIN extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675.aspx)

You can join any 2 `IEnumerables` as follows:

```
var joinedData = context1.Table1
                         .Join(context2.Table2,
                               t1 => t1.Id,    // Join Key on table 1
                               t2 => t2.T1Id,  // Join Key on table 2
                               (table1, table2) => ... // Projection
                               );
```

Where:

- Join Key on table 1 e.g. the Primary Key of Table 1 or common natural
  key
- Join Key on table 2, e.g. a Foreign Key or common natural key
- Projection : You can  whatever you want from table1 and table2, e.g.
  into a new anonymous class, such as `new {Name = table1.Name, Data = table2.SalesQuantity}`

Comment: Hi Stuart, I am getting an Error saying.. "The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts."