# Add aggregate column to Entity Framework Join() on multiple contexts

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework-5

Using results from both [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954787/how-to-join-two-table-from-two-different-edmx-using-linq-query) and [another site](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ee01e6/how-to-join-two-tables-from-different-database-using-entity/) I was able to get multiple contexts joined.  The issue is that I'd also like to Select an additional column that is a Count of a GroupBy.

```
reports =
   contacts.Join(records, c => c.ContactId, r => r.RecordId,
       (c, r) => new ReportModel
       {
           Record = r.RecordId,
           Available = r.RecordAvailable,
           Result = c.ContactResult,
           Date = c.ContactDate,
           Account = c.ContactId,
           //Total = r.Count()
       }).ToList();
```

Obviously I cannot simply expect that `r.Count()` will work as in the example.  I have tried to do the following but I am having an issue creating the complete `ReportModel` with the additional columns.

```
.GroupBy(r => new {r.RecordId})
.Select(x => new ReportModel {
           Record = r.RecordId,
           Available = r.RecordAvailable,
           Result = c.ContactResult,
           Date = c.ContactDate,
           Account = c.ContactId,
           Total = x.Count(r => r.RecordId)
  });
```

How can I use the existing `ReportModel` and also populate the Total column and other calculated or aggregated columns?

Comment: Well, it boils down to regular linq-to-objects, so there's no magic trick involved. But can you be more specific than "a Count of a GroupB" and "I am having an issue"?

Comment: I'm not able to create the correct lambda expressions to reference the fields I need. I'd like to populate the ReportModel fields with Counts of both Record by Account and Account by Record.  I'm not certain it's possible to do in a single query.